# How to stop Gluster volume forcely

Tags: volume, glusterfs

according to $ gluster volume help
`volume stop <VOLNAME> [force] - stop volume specified by <VOLNAME>`

But even I run this accordingly.
`$ gluster volume stop <VOLNAME> force`
it still prompted me like
`Stopping volume will make its data inaccessible. Do you want to continue? (y/n)`

How could we skip this confirmation process?

Comment: You might want to file a bug @ https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=GlusterFS  for this as `force` should not prompt for further input. If you're automating commands, `gluster --mode=script  <command>` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether this helps:

echo 'y' | gluster volume stop  force

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried so but it seems OK

Answer (score 1):

Below command will help you to skip the confirmation process.

```
echo 'y' | gluster volume stop VolumeName
```